# Large current for a short amount of time

Tags: capacitor, high-current

I need some help with design a circuit that could store charge
and pump out 16 amps to a 1.5 ohm load for 3 seconds when discharge. The load is basically two resistors in parallel, each branch with 3 ohms resistance.

Charging voltage is limited to 5volts. Discharging voltage would be 24 volts and 16 amps. current spike for 3 seconds when discharge.

Please assist, would love to your design!

Comment: This is not a free design service

Comment: 24V lead acid battery, charger and 3 second relay timer circuit. The detail is for you to figure as @PlasmaHH points out.

Comment: Andy Aka put it right...!! Since your charging voltage is only 5 volt, boost it using a DC to DC converter to charge the 24 volt battery. I assume the 5 volt supply can deliver at least 25 Amps. Free design service? We won't do that for you.

Comment: @louisfeng please provide information on the circuit you have designed. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask This community answers questions pertaining to electrical design. Asking for a free design is unprofessional, please come up with a design, if it doesn't work then we will be happy to answer your questions of where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A range of solutions exist.
Acceptable cost and size and desired cycle life need to be known

24V x 16A = 384 Watts.
Charging from 5V will require a 5V-> 24V converter. 
384W x 3 seconds ~= 1150 Joule. 
Allow say 2000 J to accommodate converter efficiency and storage losses.
At 5V energy = 5V x I J/s per amp. 
Charging time ~= 2000/(5 x I)
eg 400s at 1A, 40S at 10A and 4s at 100A (!).

Energy storage can be at 5V or 24V level.
5V storage means the 5 to 24V converter would  need to handle the 384 Watt load.

Lead acid batteries of suitable capacity would do this. 
Cars with a 30-40 Ah 12V battery will crank for short periods at say 400A or up to 20C.
2 x 12V , 7Ah 'motorcycle batteries' may meet the need - the data sheet would need to be checked re allowable discharge rates.

Other battery chemistries such as LiIon and LiFePO4 will do this with ease using modest Ah capacity cells.

A suitably sized supercap could provide the energy storage.
Capacitor energy = 1/2CV^2 or about 12.5J per Farad at 5V.
From above, for 1150 J output energy C >= 1150/12.5 = 92F. So say 200F at 5V would probably be needed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the great advice! But most supercaps are in range of below 3V, I am quite new to circuit deisng, is it possible to make it work with 2.5V 300F supercaps? Many thanks!!

Comment: @LoiusFeng Yes, but you'll need a lot of them: 10 in series to get to 25V, 30F. Put 7 of those strings in parallel and you have your 210F @ 25V. Boost Caps(TM) are available with 3000F+ and may get you there more easily. - Use a battery instead.

Comment: @JimmyB   He was talking about using an inverter from 5V to handle the peak current. I based the above on 200F at 5V. The energy content is about 2x the basic need to allow for conversion efficiency and not using all cap contents (eg drain to V/2 = 75% of energy used. Drain to 70%of Vmax = 50% of energy used.

Comment: @LouisFeng I used 5V 200F as that was your stated charge voltage. You can use eg 2 x ~= 3V caps at 2x the capacitance and some basic circuitry for balancing. eg 2 x 400F in series = 200F. Lower V is doable but the comnverter efficincy tends to be lower and as cap must discharge during loading V drops. With 5V to start you get 75% of energy supplied by Vcap = 2.5V. That's lower than ideal for a converter but doable.

Comment: @LouisFeng - a 24V battery charged by a boost converter would be an easier solution if you can tolerate the weight and size.